# Windows phone 8.1 radio

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I can't find Microsoft.Devices.Radio namespace in my project (Windows phone 8.1)
this is namespace exists in my previous project for Windows phone 8 silverlight

Any ideas ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is [no  direct equivalent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/porting/wpsl-to-uwp-namespace-and-class-mappings) in the Windows Runtime API, so you should stick with developing within Silverlight for Windows Phone